# How to correctly format a submit button in a bootstrap4 form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the following HTML code to format a bootstrap button (and form) but this button only appears correctly (in the common "btn-primary" blue colour) if I delete the `type='submit'` property.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
<div class="form" action="/submit-subject" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input" id="exampleRadios1" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" value="option1" checked="true" /><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">Default radio</label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input" id="exampleRadios2" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" value="option2" /><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input" id="exampleRadios3" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" value="option3" /><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">Disabled radio</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit-subject">Submit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try making it a `button` element instead of just a `div`

Comment: @sean: it worked. thks